# Getting yuvmotionfps working on 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to get yuvmotionfps (http://jcornet.free.fr/linux/yuvmotionfps.html) working on ubuntu 11.10 64-bit.

When I configure it normally I get errors saying "videodev.h not found"

Someone here said he managed to get it installed:
http://crazedmuleproductions.blogspot.com/2010/08/building-cincv-from-source-ubuntu-32.html?showComment=1282346714442#c7687855630832861436

When I follow these steps I still get the same errors, apparently videodev.h is depreciated so I tried replacing instances of it with videodev2.h. It would configure but not make saying "Your  does not even support "i386" for '-march' and '-mcpu'". Is it possible to get it working for 64-bit ubuntu or am I wasting my time?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

I got it running by commenting out the echo command for the "Your..." message in the cpuinfo.sh file. The message disturbed the expected output (mcpu march) of cpuinfo.sh which becomes part of the gcc options in the compilation process. Without this "Your..." message, mpu and march are set to empty strings, so that gcc uses the native settings.